# Why do I see posterization in photoshop (and aperture) when I don't see it on my LCD screen?

Tags: raw, apple-aperture, photoshop-elements

My usual workflow is to upload pictures to Aperture then edit them in Photoshop if necessary.

First I was disappointed when I saw the pictures in Aperture because of the posterization (worse in this picture than any others, but still visible). So I compared the pictures I had just uploaded to those on my LCD screen, and the transition between shadows and light is perfectly smooth on the LCD - even when I zoom in!
When I started editing the images in CS6, it was worse than in Aperture...

What am I doing wrong here?

Nikon D610 - RAW

The following example (potentially NSFW) is a JPEG of course (mouse over to see the image)

> [image: Black-Red-Green Bands]

Comment: LCD screens on the back of cameras lie like politicians!

Comment: Maybe I'm just not very good at this sort of thing but I'm not seeing any obvious posterisation here...  Are there specific parts of the image which you feel highlight the problem?

Comment: I'm going to suggest that either your monitor is not up to the task, or that there is something very wrong with your colour settings. I *am* pretty good at this sort of thing, and there is no visible banding/posterization on the full-sized image.

Answer (score 2):

With "LCD screen", i assume you mean your camera's screen. The better question would then be "Why can't i see the the posterization on my crappy camera LCD?" and the answer is: because it doesn't have the quality of a real monitor. Also, on the camera, you see the jpeg preview, while in Aperture you see Aperture'S rendering of the RAW file.

That said, i don't see any serious banding on this image either.

Answer (score 1):

To everyone who answered this question, thank you VERY MUCH.

Actually, the problem lied in my monitor calibration (manual calibration - advanced settings). My husband opened the images on his laptop, and it was a perfect match (in quality) with the image which appeared on my LCD camera screen. I am so relieved, because the posterization I was seeing was horrendous.
I hope this can help someone else down the line.

Obviously, I need to learn how to better calibrate my monitor now...

Thank you!